# java HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY both returning 12-hr time

Tags: java, unix-timestamp, hour

I am using the following code to try to get the HOUR_OF_DAY (0-23) of a unix timestamp, converted to milliseconds.  The timestamp '1296442971' converts to Sun Jan 30 2011 22:02:51 GMT-0500 (EST).

I'm running the following code to try to get the 24-hr timestamp:

```
    //calculate the hour for this timestamp
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz));             
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(ts * 1000);
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);  
    int twelveHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

In this example, both 'hour' and 'twelveHour' have the value 10, when 'hour' should have the value '22'.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "tz" ?  (what are you setting the time zone to)?

Comment: tz is being set as "America/New_York"

Comment: @user507016: Can you try my example in the answer and see if it prints 22 and 10 for you? It does for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming **ts** is the variable containing the value **1296442971**. I believe you have **not** declared it to be of type **long** and hence it might be overflowing

Below works after changing **ts** to long type

```
long l = 1296442971;
calendar.setTimeInMillis(l * 1000);
out.println(calendar.getTime());
out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain  this is it. If you make it an int, you get 10/10. Changing it to a long gives you 22/10.

Comment: Excellent!  I was using an int to store my timestamp.  Thanks Pangea!!

Comment: Yep, this would be it. Moral of the story is to inspect the whole date, seeing the year come up as 1970 would've made things a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This prints 22 and 10 for me respectively. That looks correct for NY (since you mentioned eastern time).

```
    long ts = 1296442971;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();       
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    calendar.setTimeZone(tz);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(ts*1000);
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);  
    int twelveHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    System.out.println("hour:"+hour);
    System.out.println("twelvehour:"+twelveHour);
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? It's not very nice to leave a down vote without a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost certainly that you're using an `int` to hold the seconds. Type in the following program which checks `int` and `long`:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class scratch {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

        int intval = 1296442971;
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(intval * 1000);
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);  
        int twelveHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        System.out.println (hour);
        System.out.println (twelveHour);

        long longval = 1296442971L;
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(longval * 1000);
        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);  
        twelveHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        System.out.println (hour);
        System.out.println (twelveHour);
    }
}
```

and you get:

```
10
10
22
10
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is working on your system. On my machine it prints 10 and 10 and the calendar.getTime() prints "Wed Dec 24 10:00:47 EST 1969"

Comment: Then your time appears to be cactus. That's one week before the epoch! What is the time when you request it from your system (rather than Java) such as with the date command under UNIX?

Comment: currently the time on my machine is 12.21 AM EST so the time and date are fine on my machine

Comment: @Pangea - ints are signed in Java, so you're overflowing to a negative value (just going back in time really ;)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_296_442_971L )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )
       .getHour()
```

> 23

…for value: `2011-01-30T23:02:51-04:00[America/New_York]`

## 32-bit vs 64-bit integers

As the other answers correctly noted, you must use a 64-bit `long` or `Long` to track the number of milliseconds since 1970 in UTC. Your number `1296442971` is the number of whole seconds since 1970 in UTC. When multiplied by 1,000 to get milliseconds-since-epoch, you overflow the limit of a 32-bit `int` or `Integer`.

## java.time

Another problem is that you are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

The `Instant` class has a factory method for importing a number of whole seconds since epoch.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_296_442_971L );
```

> instant.toString(): 2011-01-31T03:02:51Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

To see the wall-clock time of the east coast US, apply a `ZoneId` for a time zone such as `America/New_York` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2011-01-30T23:02:51-04:00[America/New_York]

Interrogate for the hour-of-day in 24-hour numbering of 0-23 by calling [`getHour`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#getHour--).

```
int hourOfDay = zdt.getHour();
```

> 23

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.