# Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY always showing 1 hour advance and 12 Hour Format

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

My code

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    thisHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    Log.e(TAG + "--thisHour: ",String.valueOf(thisHour));
```

So this should print the hour of day as 24 hour format. When tried, then Time was 2.10pm so it should print 14. But it always print in log 3. I tried at other times too but same result. Always print time 1 hour advance and in 12 hour format. What have I done wrong ! Need guidline

Comment: your code is working fine. check your device time

Comment: [Duplicate] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539540/java-calendar-hour-of-day-returning-12-hour-format

Comment: @Destro donno whats happening

Comment: ya i have check your code then find 14 in log

Comment: Actually it isn't a duplicate, because he is complaining of the hour being WRONG, not just in 12hours format.

Comment: @mawalker exactly . and alrdy searced stackover flow .

Comment: @Destro thanks . There was a problem in my device.

Comment: out of curiosity.... what problem?

Comment: @mawalker Genymotion Emulator showing this weird problem. On real device its okay.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue related to timezone or daylight savings, etc.

Have you tried [getTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) and [getTimeZone()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeZone()) to verify that the information being returned is what you expect? or even [toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#toString()) which should print everything in a readable format for you.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Problem is solved. It was device related problem